# failing to use LocalNotificationCallBack to display a form that displays a notification using Codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I am using LocalNotifications to display messages when the user is not inside the app. The challenge now is the callback. The form I am creating is not showing after evoking the callback. Here is a my code for the callback

```
  if (notificationId.startsWith("prospect")) {

        Display.getInstance().callSerially(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // this occurs on the EDT so I can make changes to UI components
                String id = StringUtil.tokenize(notificationId, "-").get(1);

                Container cc = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
                String info = "We have hit the\n" + "end of the line";

                /*SpanLabel sp = new SpanLabel("Type: " + c.getTaskType()
                            + "\nNotes: " + notNullOrEmpty(c.getNotes()) + "\nWhen: "
                            + new Date(Long.parseLong(c.getTimestamp()))
                            + "\n Venue: " + c.getVenue(), "DialogBody");*/
                SpanLabel sp = new SpanLabel(info);
                sp.setRTL(false);

                sp.setTextBlockAlign(Component.LEFT);

                cc.add(sp);
                Form f = new Form("Prospect Alert", new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

                final Command back = new Command(null) {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

                        main.show();
                    }
                };

                f.add(cc);

                f.setBackCommand(back);
                f.show();
                f.repaint();
                //main.removeAll();
                //main.setTitle("Prospect Alert");
                // main.removeAllCommands();
                //main.add(sp);
                //main.revalidate();
                //mainStage.removeAll();
                // BorderLayout bl = new BorderLayout();
                // mainStage.setLayout(bl);
                //mainStage.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, sp);

            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The callback can be invoked before the `start` method is invoked and that method might override your settings. Make the `currentForm` variable in the main class static then you can do something like:

```
MyMainClass.currentForm = f;
```

Comment: The form shows but only after i tap or click on the form. This is my code 


            f.add(cc);

            f.setBackCommand(back);
            //f.show();
            //f.repaint();
            MyMainClass.main = f;
            MyMainClass.main.revalidate();
            MyMainClass.main.repaint();
            MyMainClass.main.show();
           // main.removeAll();
           // main.setTitle("Prospect Alert");
            //main.removeAllCommands(

Comment: You don't need a repaint() after show() and it might cause a problem. My solution would still be applicable since both forms are shown and you get a midair collision. My suggested solution would solve that.

Comment: Yes i realized then proceeded to solve that exact problem. The solution was a delay since start method is invoked first and then show form  Used UITimer with a 1 second delay. Thanks for the direction